# Adding a class path to jar file

Tags: java, xml, jar, classpath, manifest

I got a tester program that will run from a jar file the jar file needs to include a classpath to be able to fined the tests classes in the same directory where the jar file is. The test class will not be in the jar file but will be in the same folder as the the jar file

I searched and fined some usage of a manifest.txt file or a xml file with the classpath in but never knew how to add it to my jar file when I build it.

Comment: Although it's possible to add a classpath *into* a jar file, I wouldn't recommend it as it can be a source of errors and obviously it needs to be manually updated to edit it. Use a command line 'one-time' classpath. e.g. `java -cp /some/classes:xyz.jar foo.bar.Tester`

Comment: I do not think that this would work because I do not know where the Jar file will be when we run it. so I need a whey to tell it that when I run you and give you the name of the test class it will be in the same directory as you are in when you run.

Comment: Creating a jar file is yet another thing to issue a command for. I really don't know why you're not using a build tool to do that as well